# Insecure content warning on ssl page with unsubmitted http form

Tags: https, google-chrome

On the secure https section of a website, I just found out that I had an insecure content warning that was killing the "lock" functionality and hurting conversions (because users didn't have the green lock and were being turned away by that).

The content warning was on a form that was for a google search via http.  In other words, a search box that was **not being submitted** now causes the content warning message on secure pages in google chrome 37!

This was killing conversions for me, and I'd love to be able to pin down when this change was introduced to the wild.  Does anyone know anything about that change, or have a way to figure out when the change would have been introduced?

Comment: I don't think  matters if its being submitted, If you simply have internal elements being called via http and not https URLs it will cause the insecure warning. All internal elements must be called via https

Comment: Indeed, however, that's a change from previous behavior.